# how to edit config php file with setting file

Tags: php

i have a little script and i want to give possibility to the user to edit the "**config.php**" file , with the script in the (**setting.php**) page .

For Example , they are some of codes in "config.php"

```
$title = 'myblog';
$email = 'info@google.com';
$desc = 'Something';
```

i want to have a "**HTML**" page , to get the value of the things that i said. 
(the user enter the value and the value should be used in other parts of script)

Comment: You want to literally change the config.php file? Where do you use it for? Sounds like a risky thing to do. What have you tried to accomplish this so far?

Comment: Hi putvande, this config file Sets the site title and admin email in every place that i call it . so i want the user set his own in a html form. like wordpress main setting page :)

Comment: Are you sure you need a file for this instead of a database?

Comment: @Sebas i have the database now. i just want the HTML code to use !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should better do this:
In the settings.php file:

```
<form action="settings2.php" method="POST">
Title:<input type="test" name="title"><br>
Email:<input type="test" name="email"><br>
Desc:<input type="test" name="desc"><br>
<input type="submit">
```

And settings2.php:

```
<?php
$title = $_POST['title'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$desc = $_POST['desc'];

    $content= '<?php
    $title = "'.$title.'";
    $email = "'.$email.'";
    $desc = "'.$desc.'";
    ?>';

    $file = "config.php";
    $fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $content);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

These 2 pages will put in config.php the values submited by the form, for example:

```
<?php
        $title = "PHP";
        $email = "email@email.com";
        $desc = "something";
        ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

if you want something like the user can change the title, if there are more than one user means if one changes config.php the title will be changed for the rest.
so, it's better to use a databases.

if it's only one user, you can use a file to store the information in.

please, explain more what you want to do, one user or more than one ?